# Twig variable scope includes, macro

Tags: symfony, twig

I'm just desperate for twig variable scopes.

I have several places where I set a URL and a target and since this always happens in the same scheme, I wanted to outsource the logic:

```
{% set externalKey = itemType ~ "ButtonLinkExternal" %}
{% set internalKey = itemType ~ "ButtonLink" %}

{% if item[externalKey] is not empty %}
    {% set buttonUrl = item[externalKey] %}
    {% set buttonTarget = 'target=_blank' %}
{% elseif item[internalKey] %}
    {% set buttonUrl = "/" ~ app.request.locale ~ sulu_content_load(item[internalKey]).content.url %}
    {% set buttonTarget = 'target=_self' %}
{% endif %}
```

This is one of the way, I have tried to include it:

```
{% include ':templates/modules/partials:buttonUrl.html.twig' with {'item': snippet.content.boxes.0, 'itemType': 'box'} %}
```

I also tried it with a macro, which also had the same behavior.

Moreover I have set the variable before including the template to get out of the scope of the included file.

Because I am using another twig function, to load an internal URL I can not create a twig function.

Is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: Which variables aren't know? Each variable know in a main template should be known in an include if you are not using `with only`. Macro's do have their own private scope so it would not work with macro's unless passing the variables

Comment: `buttonUrl` and `buttonTarget`. Both are defined before the include as empty string and then set in the included file as shown above. But when using them after the include they are empty again

Comment: Ah like that, no is not possible, values are passed by value to an include